# laravel Storage link

Tags: laravel, storage

we all know that we need to do

```
php artisan storage:link
```

To link the root storage of our app into the public folder so we can share it with
users but my problem is when I do

```
php artisan storage:link
```

It linkes and everything look good but after maybe 3 weeks or more it breaks the link and I should relink it I just wanted to ask why is this happening with me
I don't want this to happen with my client bcs it will sabotage a lot of functions

Comment: Sounds like something calls git revert

Comment: thanks i will look for that and tell you what happenes

Comment: what is the OS?

Comment: the os is windows 7

Comment: @simonecosci i couldn't find any function or anthing that calls git revert and for sure i didn't do that manually

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "breaks the link" means? Is the link gone? Pointing to the wrong spot? Do you have some sort of deployment process that might be doing this?

Comment: what i mean is that when it breaks the storage folder in the public stay like normal but when you upload a picture and you want it to show it to the user it gives you an icon of corrupted picture then you must relink it using the command and for your second question I don't think there is anything doing this because i checked almost everything and everything looks good